# How can improve the efficiency of my isometric tile render algorithm?

Tags: javascript, performance, html5-canvas

I'm developing a HTML5 2D isometric game engine (think sim city 2000). I'm looking to improve the frame-rate and I've got a feeling my code is vastly inefficient. Below is the code which loops through all the tile sprites from the back of the map (north) to the front (south):

```
var xTile = 0;
var yTile = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < mapWidth; i++) {
    for (var j = mapHeight; j >= 1; j--) {
        // What tile are you drawing?
        var currentTile = new Image();
        if (mapArray[i][j - 1] === "g") {
            currentTile = grass;
        }
        else if (mapArray[i][j - 1] === "s") {
            currentTile = sand;
        }
        else if (mapArray[i][j - 1] === "w") {
            currentTile = water;
        }

        // Calculate where to draw the tile
        xPosition = ((j * tileWidth / 2) + (i * tileWidth / 2));
        yPosition = ((i * tileHeight / 2) - (j * tileHeight / 2));

        if (currentTile.height !== 32) {
           yPosition = yPosition - (currentTile.height - 32);
        }

        // draw tile
        ctx.drawImage(currentTile, locationModifierX + xPosition - (tileWidth / 2), locationModifierY + yPosition + 250 - (heightArray[i][j - 1] * 16));

        yTile++;

        // Return to the beginning of the y row if the end has been reached
        if (yTile >= 16) {
            yTile = 0;
        }
    }
    xTile++;
}
```

Basically I'm trying to understand how I can improve the speed and efficiency of the draw cycle, as I imagine its even more important with a browser based game than normal. I guess I'll judge the best answer as the first to provide a decent frame rate improvement.

I hope the question isn't too vague but there are a multitude of potential answers I suppose...

*possible improvement* -----

```
    var xTile = 0;
    var yTile = 0;
    var currentTile = new Image();

    // Tile Loop
    for (var i = 0; i < mapWidth; i++) {
        for (var j = mapHeight; j >= 1; j--) {        

            // What tile are you drawing?
            if (mapArray[i][j - 1] === "g") {
                currentTile = grass;
            }
            else if (mapArray[i][j - 1] === "s") {
                currentTile = sand;
            }
            else if (mapArray[i][j - 1] === "w") {
                currentTile = water;
            }
```

Comment: `var currentTile = new Image();` is likely to be deadly. No reason to create an object here, and creating a native DOM object is heavy.

Comment: Would simply defining this outside of the loop help?

Comment: No, just do `var currentTile;`. You don't need to assign anything. (Or are there any non-g/s/w tiles? Then you should create *one* empty image with which the variable is initialised).

Comment: Isn't it better to do this outside of the tile draw loop?

Comment: Creating the empty image? Yes, that's what I meant by emphasizing "one".

Comment: See the *possible improvement* that I've added. Is that what you mean?

Many thanks

Comment: No, I meant to either totally drop `= new Image()` if you don't need it, or `var empty = new Image(); for( […] { var currentTile=empty; if(…){ currentTile=nonempty; }` if you need it to handle tiles that don't match any of the if-branches.

Comment: I would recommend you to run your code with a profiler to see which parts of the code take how much of a share of the total execution time. Bottlenecks are sometimes where you least expect them to be.

Comment: Thanks - I'll research profilers, I've already added some code to handle clipping and implemented a fps limit.